# Problems in dynamically generating an Image in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image

I am dynamically adding an image to a canvas object which was working for a while and suddenly stopped displaying for some particular reason.

Here is the code :

```
public void shootProjectile()
{

    var projectileImage = new Image();
    var currChar = (CharactersRef.SCharacterProjectile)lstSubMenu.SelectedItem;
    projectileImage.Name = currChar.projectileName;
    Uri imageUri = new Uri("/Images/Projectiles/"+ currChar.projectileName +".png", UriKind.Relative);

    projectileImage.Height = currChar.projectileHeight;
    projectileImage.Width=currChar.projectileWidth;
    var currPuppet = pg.PuppetList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.puppetID == turnID);
    var projectileY = Convert.ToDouble(pcCombatArea.PhysicsObjects[currPuppet.CharacterName+"torso"].GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));
    var projectileX = Convert.ToDouble(pcCombatArea.PhysicsObjects[currPuppet.CharacterName + "torso"].GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));

    if (currPuppet.faceRight)
    {
        projectileX += currPuppet.elbowToArmpit + currPuppet.elbowToHandTip;
    }
    else
    {
        projectileX -= currPuppet.elbowToArmpit + currPuppet.elbowToHandTip;
    }           
    projectileImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,projectileX);
    projectileImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, projectileY);
    cnvGame.Children.Add(projectileImage);
    projectileImage.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
    projectileImage.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(projectileImage_ImageOpened);
}
```

The Top and Left values are well in the range of the canvas size, (The canvas is 800 by 600 whilst the coordinates are round 200, 100). I can find the images in the canvas children, and the url seems to be ok, I double checked it. I set the png image Build type to resource but to no avail. If you notice I have added an ImageOpened even which is not being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the image build type set to Resource, then try removing the leading '/' from the image URI.

Comment: Changed the build type to content and it worked, will try out resource later